# Optimize and (re)save saved-model with grappler

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I've got a **(TF2) saved-model** full of **training ops clutter** and I'm trying to **optimize it for inference** using grappler, but I want to **save it back to a TF2 saved-model subsequently** (to keep the general workflow away from TF1).

I currently have:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph
from tensorflow.lite.python.util import run_graph_optimizations, get_grappler_config

# Load the saved-model and get the inference concrete function
sm = tf.saved_model.load('path/to/savedmodel/dir')
func = sm.signatures['serving_default']

# Replace variables with constants in order to get rid of the training clutter
frozen_func, graph_def = convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph(func)

# Use grappler to optimize the concrete function graph after replacing vars with constants
input_tensors = [tsr for tsr in frozen_func.inputs if tsr.dtype != tf.resource]
output_tensors = frozen_func.outputs
graph_def = run_graph_optimizations(graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors,
                                    config=get_grappler_config(["constfold", "function"]),
                                    graph=frozen_func.graph)

# Here the intention is to somehow reconvert the optimized graph-def into a concrete function
# and subsequently re-save that as a TF2(not TF1!) saved-model, is there a way to do that?
frozen_func_graph = tf.Graph()
with frozen_func_graph.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

# ... what now?
```

The issue is, since **[direct tf.Graph usage has been deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#using_graphs_directly_deprecated)** in TF2, I intend to convert the optimized graph back to a TF2 saved-model. I was thinking of doing that by somehow manually constructing a ConcreteFunction wrapping this optimized graph, but as far as I've researched, there seems to be now way to do that. This would basically mean I'd still have to use TF1 compat APIs, which ideally I'd like to avoid.

The **ugly (ugly) option** I'd really like to avoid would be (haven't tried it yet but would probably work):

- use v1 APIs to construct a TF1 saved-model using **tf.compat.v1.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder** and **save the TF1 saved-model**
- **load back the TF1 saved-model** using v2 API (so tf.saved_model.load instead of tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load, the former converts a TF1 saved-model automatically to a TF2 saved-model)
- (re)**save the converted TF2 saved-model**

Is there a way to do this nicely? Preferably also without being forced to dump the optimized saved-model if I don't want to, seems that constructing saved-models in memory is not possible? (that's not such a big issue though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it, not ideal since I use internal (more or less) TF2 API calls, but at least TF1 compat APIs are not used at all. Here's the full code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework.convert_to_constants import convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph
from tensorflow.lite.python.util import run_graph_optimizations, get_grappler_config
from tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference_lib import optimize_for_inference
from tensorflow.python.eager import context, wrap_function

# Load the saved-model and get the inference concrete function
sm = tf.saved_model.load('path/to/savedmodel/dir')
func = sm.signatures['serving_default'] # note: key might differ according to what your model's inference function is

# Replace variables with constants in order to get rid of the training clutter
frozen_func, graph_def = convert_variables_to_constants_v2_as_graph(func)

# Use grappler to optimize the concrete function graph after replacing vars with constants
input_tensors = [tsr for tsr in frozen_func.inputs if tsr.dtype != tf.resource]
output_tensors = frozen_func.outputs
graph_def = run_graph_optimizations(graph_def, input_tensors, output_tensors,
                                    config=get_grappler_config(["constfold", "function"]),
                                    graph=frozen_func.graph)

# Optimize for inference
input_tsr_names = [tsr.name for tsr in input_tensors]
output_tsr_names = [tsr.name for tsr in output_tensors]
input_node_names = list(set([tsr_name.rsplit(':', 1)[0] for tsr_name in input_tsr_names]))
output_node_names = list(set([tsr_name.rsplit(':', 1)[0] for tsr_name in output_tsr_names]))
graph_def = optimize_for_inference(input_graph_def=graph_def,
                                   input_node_names=input_node_names,
               placeholder_type_enum=tf.dtypes.float32.as_datatype_enum,
                                   output_node_names=output_node_names,
                                   toco_compatible=True)

# This next part inspired from _construct_concrete_function function here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/convert_to_constants.py#L1062

# Remove old functions to use updated functions from graph def - not sure if this is actually needed here, didn't look into it
for f in graph_def.library.function:
    if context.context().has_function(f.signature.name):
        context.context().remove_function(f.signature.name)

# GraphDef to concrete function
opt_frozen_func = wrap_function.function_from_graph_def(graph_def,
                                                        input_tsr_names,
                                                        output_tsr_names)

# Wrap concrete function into module to export as saved-model
class OptimizedFrozenModel(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super().__init__(name)

module = OptimizedFrozenModel()
module.__call__ = opt_frozen_func

# Export frozen & optimized saved-model
tf.saved_model.save(module, 'path/to/optimized_savedmodel/dir', signatures=opt_frozen_func)
```

Comment: How deep have you had to research archeology! I'll certainly try in v2.13/.15 that I have, and let you know if it's become borked—or edit your response (you'll get a notification, IIRC for a second look, which I'd truly appreciate). You would mind answering a question, wouldn't you, should you perchance have time for it? I guess that when more that one named traced function graph is exported, I'll find them in the same `sm.signatures` object, will I? I'd profounly appreciate and anxiously await your reply, but by all means don't bend backwards if it cut into your schedule. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @kkm-stillwaryofSEpromises, IIRC you can get the list of the sub-functions of a graph using graph._functions (dict names/values; if you find a way to avoid accessing private members directly that would be nice) and to get a function's graph you'd use func.graph. Most of the times 'signatures' only contains a subset of these functions (the "entrypoints" of interest), depending on how the model is exported. So in short you can probably recursively find all the subgraphs of a function F by using it's F.graph._functions dict.